# PInvokeStackImbalance - when I call a delphi function in C#

Tags: c#, delphi

I need to call a delphi function in C #, but in doing so it has an exception: pinvokestackimbalance. I visited several forums but I did not find a solution !! I will demonstrate my code. I hope you can help me.

Here's the function in Delphi: 
function recebeTabFuncionarios (Host : ShortString; NomeArquivo : ShortString)

Already tried changing the CallingConvention from StdCall to Cdecl, but without success! 
I tried to pass the parameters of the function without using 'MarshalAs' but without success also.

```
[DllImport("InforAcesso.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "recebeTabFuncionarios")]
        static extern string recebeTabFuncionarios([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string sHost, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]  string sArquivo);


static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string sTeste = recebeTabFuncionarios("192.168.0.100", "Teste.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.Write(err.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
            }           
        }
```

Exception:

'A call to the PInvoke function' ConsoleDelphiDll! ConsoleDelphiDll.Program :: getTabFunctional 'unbalanced the stack. The said request for signature does not correspond to the signature of the contract. "To obtain a convention and the PInvoke signature call parameter, signature of destination is not allowed."

Comment: What is the function declaration in the Delphi?  The default calling convention in Delphi is "register" -- I don't know if .NET even knows about that one.  If you can, the simplest thing to do is specify stdcall in the Delphi code.

Comment: The Delphi code is invalid because no return type is specified. You can't use ShortString directly, it's a Delphi specific type. There are hundreds of examples of passing strings. Do some research and start from the basics. Can you call a function with a single parameter that accepts text? Going to be PAnsiChar or PWideChar in the Delphi.

Comment: I have nothing to add on the thematic, but exception handling is a pet peeve of mine. And yours is bad. You catch way to wide and only log the message. Here are two articles on proper exception handling that I linke often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @Christopher For a single statement MCVE, poor exception handling might be acceptable...

Comment: @GolezTrol: What he has there will at best result in incomplete debugging information. And at worst swalled exceptions with all the inevitable followup exceptions. And if that made it into an example, this is likely a Systemic issue across the code.

Comment: @Christopher My guess is that the exception handling here is simply for the purpose of the example, so that the error message can be observed. In reality there should be no `catch` around such a function call because an unmanaged DLL is contracted not to throw exceptions, and once the pinvoke has been correctly implemented, the .net framework won't throw any either.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: And to make certain of that I mentioned it, like I do everywhere else I see it. So apparently we agree on it being a bad thing. I do not quite understand why you read like you disagree with me here?

Comment: @Christopher I don't disagree with you but I find that your comment distracts from the actual issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it would not have distracted at all, if you and Golez had not started at 18 hour discussion about it. I already said it was not fully on topic and "a pet peeve of mine". In literally the first sentence. So it was never an issue until you decided to make it one.

Comment: Hey devs, thanks for the comments!!! 
So the only references I have to this delphi dll is a manual where it contains all the functions. I didn't quote but this function that I used returns a shortString.

Comment: I think the problem is parameter passing, because if we look at the exception that was thrown: The said request for signature does not correspond to the signature of the contract. "To get a convention and the PInvoke signature call parameter, signature of destination is not allowed."

Comment: And yes there is a test application, I need to use this dll in an ASP.Net project, but as I never used a delphi dll I decided to create a console application just test.